# Disable a link in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The first example didn't work. I need to have always a list to disable links? Or what is wrong with my first demo?

```
<a class="disabled" href="#">Disabled link</a>
```

---

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  ...
  <li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a href="#">Disabled link</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7y0u2amy/

Comment: Had a quick look at the docs, looks like disabled is only available for form items.

Answer (score 160):

I think you need the **btn** class.

It would be like this:

```
<a class="btn disabled" href="#">Disabled link</a>
```

Comment: Or maybe better, use `btn-link` to keeps the looks of a link.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen But with `btn-link` `disabled` doesn't work properly because `pointer-events: none;` isn't applied (Bootstrap 3)

Comment: Nice; a small addition - if you have the <a> embedded within an inline text, you would want to remove the padding added by btn by adding `p-0` as well. You may also want to remove the outline added when focusing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053181/how-to-remove-focus-around-buttons-on-click

Comment: With Bootstrap 5 you do not have to append any javascript logic.

Answer (score 83):

It seems that Bootstrap doesn't support disabled links. Instead of trying to add a Bootstrap class, you could add a class by your own and add some styling to it, just like this:

```css
a.disabled {
  /* Make the disabled links grayish*/
  color: gray;
  /* And disable the pointer events */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Make the disabled links unfocusable as well -->
<a href="#" class="disabled" tabindex="-1">Link to disable</a><br/>
<a href="#">Non-disabled Link</a>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that "pointer-events" has some limitations. From the Bootstrap 3 documentation: "This class uses pointer-events: none to try to disable the link functionality of <a>s, but that CSS property is not yet standardized and isn't fully supported in Opera 18 and below, or in Internet Explorer 11. In addition, even in browsers that do support pointer-events: none, keyboard navigation remains unaffected, meaning that sighted keyboard users and users of assistive technologies will still be able to activate these links. So to be safe, use custom JavaScript to disable such links."

Comment: Disabling pointer events will not display tooltip if user required it. <a href="#" title="The reason is...." class="disabled" tabindex="-1">Link to disable</a>

Answer (score 9):

I just created my own version using CSS. As I need to disabled, then when document is ready use jQuery to make active. So that way a user cannot click on a button until after the document is ready. So i can substitute with AJAX instead. The way I came up with, was to add a class to the anchor tag itself and remove the class when document is ready. Could re-purpose this for your needs.

CSS:

```
a.disabled{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-info disabled">Link Text</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.disabled').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }).removeClass('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If what you're trying to do is disable an a link, there is no option to do this. I think you can find an answer that will work for you in this question here.

One option here is to use

```
<a href="/" onclick="return false;">123n</a>
```

[Disabled href tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag)

Comment: You can mimic the styles of a disabled link in CSS by using 
.disabled{
   cursor:not-allowed;
   color:#eee;
}

Comment: still clickable though

Answer (score 4):

You cant set links to "disabled" just system elements like input, textfield etc.

But you can disable links with jQuery/JavaScript

```
$('.disabled').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Just wrap the above code in whatever event you want to disable the links.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed 'href' attribute from that anchor tag which I want to disable

```
$('#idOfAnchorTag').removeAttr('href');

$('#idOfAnchorTag').attr('class', $('#idOfAnchorTag').attr('class')+ ' disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @jacob-van-lingen's comment, You can extend `.btn-link` in your global style

```
a.disabled{
  @extend .btn-link
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed the following solution because when I apply class styles such as `btn disabled` offered by **Bootstrap 5** to an `<a>` element inside a card, margin and padding are applied to the element:

[image]

```css
.disabled {
    color: currentColor;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="disabled">Disabled Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the answer by Sercan and I added a tiny jQuery to it, so that the links are also not followed on click:

```
    $(document)
        .on("click",
            "a.disabled",
            function () {
                return false;
            });
```

and for the look from the Answer above:

```
.disabled {
   color: currentColor;
   cursor: not-allowed;
   opacity: 0.5;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class="pe-none".
Find the bootstrap link [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/interactions/).

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary pe-none" target="_blank" href="#" role="button">Open</a>
```