# Button retains focused after click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-router

I have a button, that when clicked, navigates to another route. The relative code is:

```
<button (click)="goBack()" mat-button
      aria-label="Previous Screen" role="navigation">
      <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon>
</button>
```

And the click handler:

```
  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }
```

When I click the button, the route changes, but the button gains focus. Is that what am I doing wrong?

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: I would argue that it is good that an element with which the user interacts gains focus, and I would argue that it is good that the user is aware where the focus is. Why? Accessibility.

Comment: This flow is natural and also user-friendly. Do you wish to change focus?

Comment: I would go with adi's solution. But its probably a bug in the angular material design library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to be looking at the `HTMLElement.blur()` functionality. I'm not too familiar with Angular, but you need to have access to the event and its target in order to do so.

Something like this should work:

```
<button (click)="goBack($event)" mat-button
      aria-label="Previous Screen" role="navigation">
      <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon>
</button>
```

And for the JS:

```
goBack(event) {
    event.target.blur()
    this.location.back();
  }
```

Comment: Instead of using `blur()` you should move focus to the heading of the new route, or perhaps back to the top of the document. I wrote a library to take care of this: https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-angular-router

Comment: it should be the `event.currentTarget.blur()`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be:

```
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

However, removing the outline from a button is definitely bad for accessibility. There are users who can't control a mouse, and need to be able to tab through a page with the keyboard. Removing the outline makes that very difficult. It's probably better to prevent the button from receiving focus on click.

In my opinion, calling `e.preventDefault()` in `onMouseDown` is a cleaner solution. This is certainly an accessibility friendly solution (however the solution may not be compatible with your project).

Multiple clean and accesible solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053181/how-to-remove-focus-around-buttons-on-click/37580028#37580028).

Cheers!

Comment: @danielnixon Did you read my entire answer before down-voting? I clearly stated that `outline: none` is a quick solution, but it is bad for accessibility and I mentioned some cleaner solutions + a link to another SO answer with extra explanation.