# How to remove focus around text input dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have this HTML page:

[image: HTML Page]

What I want to do is, remove that black border around my text input. But since my 'things to do' list is created dynamically (it's empty when the page loads), I want to remove the border using my JavaScript file.

How shall I do it?

Comment: Dynamic or not you should be able to remove the focus glow with pure css. Like `input { outline: none; }`

Comment: use `outline:none`

Comment: yes, you can add style attribute or using class

Comment: Yeah damn, didn't know the .css file could style future elements! Thanks

Comment: But I have to caution doing this! Focus is *very important* for accessibility and trying to navigate a web page using a keyboard instead of a mouse. If you don't know what element has focus, you have no idea what is going to happen when you press a key or hit enter!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove focus around buttons on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053181/how-to-remove-focus-around-buttons-on-click)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I see the potential risk, but is the cursor blinking (and the user typing there) not enough?

Comment: Maybe an idea is to create the CSS rule about it and toggle the class dynamically when you click the button. Doing so you are in control of how to display, how long to display it, color etc

Comment: Thanks I got it guys, I just did it in the .css file

Comment: @DhruvErry "*is the cursor blinking (and the user typing there) not enough?*" Not if they can't see it :) Accessibility and keyboard navigation is crucial for the blind and partially sighted.

Comment: The ridiculously hideously ugly thick black border was added in chrome 83.  It's ugly.  There's currently still no reliable way to style it in all cases.  See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1084974

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `document.getElementById("input'sID").style.outline = "none";` or `document.querySelector("input").style.outline="none"`; this will set the outline property of input box containing a specific id to none through javascript. or it won't effect even if the input types render dynamically, you may set `input{ outline: none}` in css and it will work for all input types rendered dynamicaaly on your page.

Comment: Thanks @Ritika, I simple add the style to my input tag and it work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

When you create this `input` field, just make sure the `autofocus` attribute is set to `false` or just don't add it.

you can also cancel it (even though the defult is `false`) like this:

```
document.getElementById("id_Of_The_Element").autofocus = false;
```