# How to remove the outline border from a button when this one was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an HTML5 game, and I have a reset button. whenever the button is clicked, it gets a black outline around the outside next time a button is pressed. is there an attribute or something I can use to prevent this?

`<button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>`

This is what I'm using for my button. I don't know if it's something in the HTML or CSS. I tried going into CSS and adding `user-select: none;` but I think that's for radio buttons

Comment: are you trying to remove onfocus outline?

Answer (score 0):

```
button, button:hover, button:active, button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be outline, set outline: none; it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I get what you're asking; probably duplicated at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053181/how-to-remove-focus-around-buttons-on-click)

The following can work for your case:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="this.blur();">
```

Using the following style (remember that this style isn't recommended when we have accessibility in mind):

```
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

See the answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053181/how-to-remove-focus-around-buttons-on-click); try to elaborate better your questions the next time, best regards; bye