# How to pragrammatically focus on HTML element without outline?

Tags: javascript, html

**Caution: `:focus { outline: none }` should not be the answer as it also prevents outline when navigating by tab key**

Clicking a button *does not show outline* but the button becomes `document.activeElement` ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh56vvLg/)). I want to mimic this behavior *without mouse clicking*.

[image]

**The method should:**

1. make the element as `document.activeElement`.
2. not cause outline
3. still allow outline when pressing keyboard tab key

(If anyone asks, my current intention is to focus a modal dialog and return the focus to the previous focused element when the dialog is closed. This requires preventing outline for seamless experience.)

**pseudo code:**

```
showDialog();

function whenDialogClosed() {
  previouslyFocused.focus(); // should not display outline
}
```

Comment: showDialog mimics modal dialog inside of a page with normal `div`s.

Comment: This question is a little bit confusing, after a short conversation he need to simulate the focus of elements, one for the main-window and one for the simulated popup!

Comment: I modified the question and I hope it is now more understandable.

Comment: You either show outline when an element is focused or you don't. There's no two kinds of focus. If it satisfies you, you could disable outline, and reenable it on blur or keydown, so that if someone does tab, it'd be shown.

Comment: Not sure to get it either... Do you want to programmatically set the focus on an element, and only when set programmatically hide the outline? Then it's as easy as to set a class on your element, and remove it on blur.

Comment: Elements can be focused without outline ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ext7dsn0/)). It seems there is no way to mimic this except using old-IE-specific `setActive()`, however.

Comment: (Or using blur event as you said)

Comment: Be careful though, [not all UAs do fire a focus event on button's click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus)

Comment: I think what you want to do is create a style class that emulates the outline (looks the same as an outline) and then, when the dialog box opens, you assign the "outlined" class to the unfocused object, so it looks the same as if it's still focused. Then, when the focus is returned to the object, remove the "outlined" class so that the natural outline is returned (the object will look the same)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS finally [got an answer](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-focus-visible-pseudo) by adding a pseudo-class [`:focus-visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) that activates exactly when [browser decides to do](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/03/focus-visible-and-backwards-compatibility/).

> For this reason, modern browsers apply simple heuristics to determine whether or not to apply their default focus styling. In general, if an element received focus as a result of a mouse/pointer click, browsers will suppress their default focus indication.

As of 2021, [all modern browsers support this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible#browser_compatibility), however if you need to support older browsers, use [a polyfill](https://github.com/wicg/focus-visible) and do this:

```
/*
 * .js-focus-visible is automatically added to document.body
 * to ensure the rules run only in JS-supported environment
 */

.js-focus-visible .your-selector:focus:not(.focus-visible) { outline: none }
```

Demo:

```js
focusrandom.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
  const button = document.getElementById(`button${num}`);
  button.focus();
});
wofocusrandom.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
  const button = document.getElementById(`wobutton${num}`);
  button.focus();
});
```

```css
.js-focus-visible .apply button:focus:not(.focus-visible) {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/focus-visible"></script>
<p class="apply">
  With focus-visible:
  <button id="button1">1</button>
  <button id="button2">2</button>
  <button id="button3">3</button>
  <button id="button4">4</button>
  <button id="button5">5</button>
</p>
<p>
  Without focus-visible:
  <button id="wobutton1">1</button>
  <button id="wobutton2">2</button>
  <button id="wobutton3">3</button>
  <button id="wobutton4">4</button>
  <button id="wobutton5">5</button>
</p>

<button id="focusrandom">Focus random button</button>
<button id="wofocusrandom">Focus random button without focus-visible</button>
```

(From https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571098/2460034. Thank you Aaron!)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a transition to the unfocus.

```js
var dial = document.getElementById('dial');
var focused;
function openDialog(){
  document.body.className="havingFocus";
  dial.className="";
  focused = document.activeElement;
  document.getElementById('new_focus').focus();
}
function closeDialog(){
  document.body.className="";
  dial.className="hidden";  
  focused.focus();
}
```

```css
.havingFocus * {
  transition: all 0s;
  transition-delay: 20000s;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}
*:focus{
  transition-delay:0s;
  outline: 2px solid highlight;
}

div{
  margin:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  position:relative;
}
div:before{
  content:'x';
  position: absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:0px;
}

.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input value="test123"/>
<div id="dial" class="hidden">
  <input value="in dialog" id="input"/>
  <button onclick="closeDialog()" id="new_focus">close</button>
</div>
<button onclick="openDialog()">open</button>
```

Comment: Not sure what you asking.